# PostgreSQL query works on pgAdmin but not in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, database, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

The query `SELECT * FROM books WHERE (isbn || ' ' || author || ' ' || name) ILIKE '%el%'` returns

[image: output]

from the full db when executed in pgAdmin (PostgreSQL tool)

[image: full-db]

But the same query doesn't seem to work when I try to run it in Spring Boot, it returns an empty list. I do not know if my query is PostgreSQL specific or if it's native SQL, if it isn't native SQL then I guess it is reasonable that it does not work seeing as I have `nativeQuery = true` which if I have understood things correctly means that native SQL is expected. Without it, the application does not even run. If the case is as described, how do I specify that I want to use PostgreSQL in the query?

`BookController.java`

```java
@GetMapping("/search")
public String search(@RequestParam(value = "keyword") String keyword, Model model) {
    List<Book> books = bookService.search(keyword);
    model.addAttribute("books", books);
    return "books";
}
```

`BookService.java`

```java
public List<Book> search(String keyword) {
      return bookRepository.search(keyword);
}
```

`BookRepository.java`

```java
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {

    List<Book> findAll();

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE (isbn || ' ' || author || ' ' || name) ILIKE '%?%'", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Book> search(String keyword);

}
```

`Books.html` the value I am entering is `el`.

```html
<form class="col-12 col-lg-auto mb-3 mb-lg-0 me-lg-3" th:action="@{books/search}" method="get">
     <input th:name="keyword" type="search" class="form-control form-control-dark" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `?` may not be *applied* properly in the query. Change `'%?%'` to `'%' || ? || '%'` as in:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE (isbn || ' ' || author || ' ' || name) ILIKE '%' || ? || '%'", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: Not a Java programmer myself, but is this safe from SQL injection?

Comment: @FrankHeikens No, this is not related to SQL Injection. Bad choice of words. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE (isbn || ' ' || author || ' ' || name) ILIKE %?1%", nativeQuery = true)
     List<Offers> search(String keyword);
```